# How does Java handle private methods being passed as Runnables to a separate service class in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have a Spring Boot test class where I've defined a private method. I also have a helper Service class which has a simple method that accepts a Runnable and executes it.

My expectation was that the private method from the test class could not be passed and run as a Runnable in the Service class because it's private. However, in practice, the method seems to be running without any issues.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
@SpringBootTest  
public class MyTest {  
    private void myPrivateMethod() {  
        // Some code here  
    }  
  
    @Autowired  
    private MyService myService;  
  
    @Test  
    public void myTest() {  
        myService.runRunnable(() -> myPrivateMethod());  
    }  
}  
  
@Service  
public class MyService {  
    public void runRunnable(Runnable r) {  
        r.run();  
    }  
}
```

I'm confused as to why this works. I thought that private methods could not be accessed outside of the class they're defined in. Could anyone explain why this is possible?

Comment: You can simplify that lambda to `this::myPrivateMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing a private method.

In fact in Java you can't pass around methods at all<sup>*</sup>.

You're passing around an implementation of `Runnable`.

That implementation is created via `() -> myPrivateMethod()`. This is a simple way to define some code to implement a functional interface (like `Runnable`).

The `myPrivateMethod()` here is just a boring old method call. You define some code, that *happens* to call a private method. Since the method call is allowed *in this place*, you can create a `Runnable` that does this.

The code you showed is *roughly equivalent* to this:

```
myService.runRunnable(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myPrivateMethod();
  }
})
```

which creates an anonymous inner class. While using the lambda expression above doesn't necessarily create a class, it's functionally equivalent to this code.

<sup>* you might find code that *looks like* it's passing around methods, but it's always just creating implementations of interfaces that *call* those methods in one way or another.</sup>